# Corrección de código deshabilitada Visual Studio Code

Tags: vscode

Al estar programando es común que salgan las palabras delinianas de rojo, mostrando un error de código o sintaxis. Por error precione en que no me mostrara esos errores y ahora no se como revertirlo, he intentado reiniciar la extención de intellisense, buscar en las configuraciones y no he encontrado nada :(. ¿Cómo puedo revertirlo?

Estoy programando en C++ y estas son las configuraciones del `setting.json`

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 2,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Gruvbox Material Dark",
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": true,
    "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders"
}
```

Comment: Hola, denso. ¿Podrías proporcionar mayor información? Por ejemplo, que lenguaje de programación estás utilizando, información que tengas en el settings.json, etc. Así podemos ayudarte mejor, porque cada caso es un mundo. Por ejemplo uno de los lenguajes que uso es PHP y si tengo en el settings.json `"php.validate.enable": false` no me marca errores y/o warnings.

Comment: También tengo el mismo problema, intente buscar la carpeta oculta y no existe. Antes si marcaba los errores ahora nada. Me refiero a la extensión de Microsoft c++ en VSC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La eliminación de la validación de c++ se encuentra en una carpeta oculta, en la ruta donde estas compilando tu archivo, llamada `.vscode` la cual contiene un archivo `settings.json` con ajustes temporales (distintos a los ajustes generales), se encuentes especificamente para este caso de c++ esto:

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "string": "cpp",
        "iosfwd": "cpp"
    },
    "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Disabled"
}
```

basta con cambiar el "Disabled" por "Enabled" y listo. Otra opción es eliminar esa carpeta de ajustes temporales y funcionara igualmente.